# Retornar 2 valores em um foreach

Tags: vb.net, foreach, return

Gostaria de retornar dois valores em um `foreach`, podem me ajudar?

```
    For Each item In Funcao()
        teste1 = gostaria de pegar aqui o resultado 1
        teste2 = gostaria de pegar aqui o resultado 2
    Next

Private Function Funcao() As String
    Dim resultado1 As String
    Dim resultado2 As String

    resultado1 = "Teste"
    resultado2 = "Teste2"

    Return resultado1

End Function
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é isto que deseja:

```
Private Function Funcao() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Yield "Teste"
    Yield "Teste2"
End Function
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Yield.vb).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/yield-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 0):

Retornar dois valores literais em uma única variável é **impossível**, mas você pode retornar um `List<string>` com dois valores e assim usar eles no seu bloco `For Each`, enumerando o retorno de `Funcao()`:

```
Private Function Funcao() As String() ' Array enumerável
    Dim Retorno As New List(Of String)
    Dim resultado1 As String
    Dim resultado2 As String

    resultado1 = "Teste"
    resultado2 = "Teste2"

    Retorno.Add(resultado1)
    Retorno.Add(resultado2)

    ' Retorna a lista com os elementos resultado1 e resultado2
    Return Retorno.ToArray()
End Function
```

E para usar:

```
Dim Resultados As String() = Funcao()
teste1 = Resultados(0) 'Teste'
teste2 = Resultados(1) 'Teste2'
```

Se quiser enumerar:

```
For Each item In Resultados
     teste1 = item(0) 'Teste'
     teste2 = item(1) 'Teste2'
Next
```